# First leg of connection delayed. Can I claim compensation?

Tags: delays, compensation, connecting-flights

My flight to Stockholm was delayed 7 hours. However, my final destination is Berlin. I will most likely still make my connecting flight. Both flights are operated and were booked (as one itinerary) with Norwegian Air.

If Stockholm had been my final destination, I definitely would have claimed compensation. However, since I may be on time in Berlin (knock on wood), I'm not sure if I can claim the compensation for only the first leg.

[Airline policy](https://www.norwegian.com/us/booking/booking-information/legal/your-passenger-rights/) is not clear in my opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under EU FCR 261/2004 and subsequent case law, the right to compensation  due to delayed flights is calculated solely on the "time lost" at the final destination.  From [pp. 17–18 of this PDF](https://ec.europa.eu/transport/sites/transport/files/themes/passengers/news/doc/2016-06-10-better-enforcement-pax-rights/c(2016)3502_en.pdf) (bolding mine):

> *vi. ‘Long delays’ at arrival*
>
> As regards ‘long delays’, the Court has ruled that passengers, including delayed passengers, may suffer from a similar inconvenience as passengers whose flight is cancelled, consisting in a certain loss of time. Based on the principle of equal treatment, **passengers reaching their final destination with a delay of three hours or more are entitled to the same compensation (Article 7) as passengers whose flight is cancelled.**
>
> ...
>
> The Court takes the view that a delay must be assessed for the purposes of the compensation provided for in Article 7 of the Regulation, in relation to the scheduled time of arrival at **the passenger's final destination** as defined in Article 2(h) of the Regulation, **which in the case of directly connecting flights must be understood as the destination of the last flight taken by the passenger.**

In other words, you will not be eligible for compensation if you arrive at your final destination less than three hours late.

However, you are probably still eligible for "care" (meals, refreshments, etc.), as these duties are triggered by delayed *departure*, not delayed arrival.

> 3.3.1. *Delay at departure*
>
> Under Article 6(1) of the Regulation, where the departure of a flight is delayed, passengers affected by this delay have the right to ‘care’ according to Article 9, and to reimbursement and a return flight according to Article 8(1)(a).